# Static routes to a server in packet tracer

Tags: routing, packet-tracer

If a generic server with 2 NICs has been added to the network in "packet tracer 7.2.1" where NIC-1 is part of VLAN-1 and NIC-2 is part of VLAN-2 of a layer 2 switch. How to statically route incoming packets of NIC-1(from PCs of VLAN-1) to NIC-2(to VLAN-2) i.e making the server to act as a bridge.

Comment: *Routing* and *bridging* are different things...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Packet Tracer is not an emulator, but a simulator.

Devices have a specific subset of functionalities, tailored for basic network learning within Cisco courses.

The servers within P.T. doesn't run a real Operating System and only have a basic TCP/IP stack simulation.

If you want to route, you use...  ...a router, not a server.

So no you cannot use a Packet Tracer server as a router.